# Is it possible to assign key/value to a picker?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Im trying to use a picker similar to html's

```
<select>
<option value="KEY">Value</option>
</select>
```

However I can't find anything relating to this. I have something along the lines of

```
List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> KVP = {1: "test", 2: "test2"}
```

Current xaml:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="PickerStack">
                <Picker x:Name="DefaultPicker"
                        Title="---Select a map---" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding GPXList_PickerList}" 
                        SelectedIndexChanged="PickerStack_Selected" 
                        SelectedItem="{Binding PickerStack_Selection}" />
```

Current code behind:

```
    var ResultConvert = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GPSAPI_GPXList[]>(ResultJSON);
            List<int> gpxList_ID = ResultConvert.Select(x => x.gpxList_ID).ToList();
            List<string> gpxList_TrailHead_Name = ResultConvert.Select(x => x.gpxList_TrailHead_Name).ToList();
            GPXList_Dictionary = ResultConvert.ToDictionary(x => x.gpxList_ID, x => x.gpxList_TrailHead_Name);
//
            // call for my picker to be populated
            PickerView(GPXList_PickerItems);

        }

        //
        // fill the picker with retrieved API values
        public void PickerView(List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> PickerSource)
        {
            DefaultPicker.ItemsSource = PickerSource;
        }

        //
        // observe the PickerStack and retrieve values on change
        private void PickerStack_Selected(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Picker PickerSelection = sender as Picker;
            TrailText.Text = PickerSelection.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
```

And would like to just display to the user the Value but return to the program the Key

```
public List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> GPXList_PickerItems { get; set; }
```

Comment: What is the type of `GPXList_PickerList`? could you share your model class. why instead of updating `GPXList_PickerList` you are overwriting `ItemsSource` directly?

Comment: Use ItemDisplyayBinding to specify which property is displayed to the user.

Comment: @Jason the ItemDisplayBinding displays to the user, but it doesn't assign the key to that displayed value that I can tell.

Comment: @Cfun I did not notice I was doing that. Im updating the code now

Comment: The SelectedItem returns the entire KeyValuePair as an object you will need to cast

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jason commented, use [`ItemDisplayBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.picker.itemdisplaybinding?view=xamarin-forms#xamarin-forms-picker-itemdisplaybinding)

```
   <Picker x:Name="DefaultPicker"
                        Title="---Select a map---" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding GPXList_PickerList}" 
                        SelectedIndexChanged="PickerStack_Selected" 
                        SelectedItem="{Binding PickerStack_Selection}"
                        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Value}" />
```

```
void PickerStack_Selected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is Picker picker)
        int key = ((KeyValuePair<int, string>)picker.SelectedItem).Key;
}
```

Comment: Won’t sender be type Picker?

Comment: yes you are right